# How to invisible a Button for some specific condition in Android?

Tags: android, image, button

I am working on a simple Android Activity which contain 10 images and 2 Buttons i.e. "Next" and "Previous", i changed all images by click on "next" and "Previous" Button using an array and both Buttons showing on every images but i want to don't show "Previous" button when user at first image and same as don't show "Next" button when user reached at tenth (last) image.

Comment: you can hide buttons by setting btn1.setvisibility(View.Invisible)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use loop for this. When you on first activity make visibility of previous button hide. On last activity make next button invisible. You can make button invisible using-

```
btnName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

For making visible when you on second or second last image-

```
btnName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loop
        {
        if(i==0){
        btnPrev.setVisibile(View.GONE);}
        else 
        {
        btnPrev.setVisibile(View.Visible)}
        if(i==array.getSize()-1)
        {
        btnNext.setVisibile(View.GONE)};
        else
        { btnNext.setVisibile(View.VISIBLE)}
```